# Problem with removing event listener (vanilla js)

Tags: javascript, dom-events, removeeventlistener

How to remove event listener which is a method of exisiting object?
I have a code like this in main.js

```
loadSite = new LoadSite(
      'js/options.js',
      'pages/options.html',
       containerMain,
      'options-wrapper'
     );

  options.addEventListener(
   'click',
   function () {
     loadSite.loadSite();
   },
   false
   );
```

And I want to remove this listner in another module. I tried write this:

```
   import { LoadSite } from './classes/LoadSite.js';
(() => {
  const options = document.querySelector('.options'),
    loadSite = new LoadSite(
      'js/options.js',
      'pages/options.html',
      containerMain,
      'options-wrapper'
    );
  options.removeEventListener('click', function () {
    loadSite.loadSite;
  });
})();
```

But it didn't work and I don't know how to make this. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove a listener you need to pass the same listener which you registered during add.

```
function listener() {
     loadSite.loadSite();
   }
options.addEventListener('click', listener, false);
options.removeEventListener('click', listener, false);
```